# python listing and counting values

Tags: python, iterator, counter

In the sample data given below (stored in a file), I need to find  distinct 'ids' in each 'item' category in the fastest way possible. I can do this by going through each line and then finding all item sets and then count, but I am looking for a faster method such as 'Counter' or 'itemgetter'.

"infile.txt"

```
id  item
444 Anemia
444 liver
444 Anemia
444 Anemia
222 liver
222 pancreas
222 liver
222 Anemia
444 pancreas
444 pancreas
444 Anemia
001 Iiver
001 pancreas
111 pancreas
111 liver
111 liver
111 pancreas
555 pancreas
555 liver
555 pancreas
555 liver
555 pancreas
555 liver
```

I need the output something like the following

```
item    count   ids
pancreas    5   001, 111, 222, 444, 555
liver   5   111,222,444,555,001
Anemia  2   222,444
```

Comment: Instead of just posting your homework assignment, can you please post what you've tried?

Comment: A counter is not what you want here; you are collecting all unique ids, so the length of the collected ids is also your count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a defaultdict with a `set`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
with open(datafile) as f:
    for line in f:
        my_id,item = line.split()
        d[item].add(my_id)

for item in d:
    print item,len(d[item]),sorted(d[item])
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Thanks.  I think I fixed it.  Anyway, the idea should be clear enough ... I used `ids` to avoid shadowing `id` -- but it was a bad variable name as it implied there was more than one.  Changed to `my_id`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. I need to check how it behaves on very large files.